# Too many open files. Python multiprocess TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing

I am writing tcp server on Python. Os - ubuntu 12.04
The server is multiprocess. Main process is accepting connections. Accepted socket reduced and sent to the worker:

```
<main process>
h = reduce_handle(conn.fileno())
self.queue.put(h)
```

Worker creates separated Thread for this connection:

```
<worker process>
t = threading.Thread(target=sock_thread, args=(h, DBSession, Protocol))
t.start()
```

Reduced socket is recovered and working at the separeted Thread:

```
<Connection Thread>
fd=rebuild_handle(h)
sock = socket.fromfd(fd,socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

<data transmition>

sock.close()
```

Everything works fine. Today I has got an exception:

```
error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Restarting server solved this problem, but number of unclosed files are increased. I monitor it trow command line:

```
lsof | grep python | wc -l
```

What is the problem? I close each socket at the thread. All threads are normally works and finishes. sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) before socket closing raises exception: bad file descriptor.
Is there a way to close the file associated with the socket?

Thanks.

Comment: Does server on linux even need socket reducing? We have the fork after all.

Comment: Sending socket object trow queue raises exception. Each worker has around 200mb data for calculations, so fork is useless.

Comment: Which process is leaking handles: the main one or the worker ones?  In general I would suspect a leak of multiprocessing.reduction.reduce/rebuild_handle().  Try to write a minimal complete example that we can run (and if necessary post as a bug to Python :-)

Comment: The problem solved. File descriptor assotiated with socket must be manually closed. os.close(fd)