# Concurrently searching a graph in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, graph, multiprocessing, python-3.3

I'd like to create a small p2p application that concurrently processes incoming data from other known / trusted nodes (it mostly stores it in an SQLite database). In order to recognize these nodes, upon connecting, each node introduces itself and my application then needs to check whether it knows this node directly or maybe indirectly through another node. Hence, I need to do a graph search which obviously needs processing time and which I'd like to outsource to a separate process (or even multiple worker processes? See my 2nd question below). Also, in some cases it is necessary to adjust the graph, add new edges or vertices.

Let's say I have **4 worker processes** accepting and handling incoming connections via asynchronous I/O. **What's the best way for them to access (read / modify) the graph?** A single queue obviously doesn't do the trick for read access because I need to pass the search results back somehow.

Hence, one way to do it would be another queue which would be filled by the graph searching process and which I could add to the event loop. The event loop could then pass the results to a handler. However, this event/callback-based approach would make it necessary to also always pass the corresponding sockets to the callbacks and thus to the Queue – which is [nasty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386678/too-many-open-files-python-multiprocess-tcp-server) because sockets are not picklable. (Let alone the fact that callbacks lead to spaghetti code.)

Another idea that's just crossed my mind might be to create a pipe to the graph process for each incoming connection and then, on the graph's side, do asynchronous I/O as well. However, in order to avoid callbacks, if I understand correctly, I would need an async I/O library making use of `yield from` (i.e. [tulip / PEP 3156](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/)). Are there other options?

Regarding async I/O on **the graph's side**: This is certainly the best way to handle many incoming requests at once but doing graph lookups is a CPU intensive task, thus **could profit from using multiple worker threads or processes**. **The problem is**: Multiple threads allow shared data but Python's GIL somewhat negates the performance benefit. Multiple processes on the other hand don't have this problem but how can I share and synchronize data between them? (For me it seems quite impossible to split up a graph.) Is there any way to solve this problem in a nice way? Also, does it make sense in terms of performance to mix asynchronous I/O with multithreading / multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your last question: It does! But, IMHO, the question is: does it makes sense mix Events and Threads? You can check this article about hybrid concurrency models: http://bibliotecadigital.sbc.org.br/download.php?paper=3027

My tip: Start with just one process and an event loop, like in the tulip model. I'll try to explain how can you use tulip to have Events+async I/O (and threads or other processes) without callbacks at all.

You could have something like `accept = yield from check_incoming()`, which should be a tulip coroutine (check_incoming), and inside this function you could use `loop.run_in_executor()` to run your graph search in a thread/process pool (I'll explain more about this later). This function `run_in_executor()` returns a Future, in which you can also `yield from tasks.wait([future_returned_by_run_in_executor], loop=self)`. The next step would be `result = future_returned_by_run_in_executor.result()` and finally return `True` or `False`.

The process pool requires that only pickable objects can be executed and returned. This requirement is not a problem but it's implicit that the graph operation must be self contained in a function and must obtain the graph instance somehow. The Thread pool has the GIL problem since you mentioned CPU bound tasks which can lead to 'acquiring-gil-conflicts' but this was improved in the new Python 3.x GIL. Both solutions have limitations..

So.. instead of a pool, you can have another single process with it's own event loop just to manage all the graph work and connect both processes with a unix domain socket for instance..

This second process, just like the first one, must also accept incoming connections (but now they are from a known source) and can use a thread pool just like I said earlier but it won't "conflict" with the first event loop process(the one that handles external clients), only with the second event loop. Threads sharing the same graph instance requires some locking/unlocking.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you for replying after such a long time! I'm not sure if I understood everything you wrote: Are you suggesting having one process / event loop handling incoming external requests and another one which does the actual search, possibly by feeding a pool of worker threads (which requires thread-safe programming)? In any case I'm still not convinced that the graph search's performance would actually profit from using threads.

Comment: Finally, could you please elaborate on the things you wrote in the 3rd paragraph? I'm kind of confused: What exactly is `check_incoming()` supposed to do? I would expect that it just yields a new incoming (internal) search request. Also, how can I `yield from tasks.wait([future_returned_by_run_in_executor], loop=self)` **in** the future which is returned by `run_in_executor()`? Could you maybe give a code example?

Comment: Hi! about the first comment: yes, 2 processes each one with it's own event loop.. I mentioned about the thread pool but I would not use it.. Threads can't really benefit if the task is cpu bound.. But even so, this is better on python 3 than 2.

Comment: About the 2nd comment:check_incoming would handle read events on the listen socket. Just accept() a connection and check if your want to close or keep it and then return the client it self (file descriptor or some high level object) or None.. Last Question: run_in_executor returns a Future wrapping the executor task. when the executor finishes and call it's callback, this returned future has it's result set. So.. tasks.wait() is a way to of wait (but not blocking since it will give the control to the event loop) for all futures have it's results set. when it happens the yield from continues

Comment: Thank you very much!
Let me rephrase your answer to make sure I got it right: You would not only do the handling of incoming requests in an asynchronous way but also the actual searching, i.e. the search algorithm would give control back to the event loop when it deems it necessary. That means it would do the classic approach to userland threads: Split up large computations into small pieces (as long as it doesn't matter if the data / the graph changes in between those pieces) in order to allow for "concurrent" searches.

Comment: Final question: How would you go about making use of several CPU cores? You mentioned that Python's GIL improved in version 3 but it in how far does it now allow threads to actually run in a concurrent way on let's say 4 cores?